# Bootstrap dropdown doesn't work consecutively

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Newbie to CSS/JS here, so please pardon my ignorance.  I have a menu that contains a dropdown menu. I am using Bootstrap.js (v3.3.5) and bootstrap.css (v3.2.0) in:

```
..
    <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <!--<link href="/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet"/>-->
    <!--<link href="http://bootswatch.com/united/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
...
 <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-transparent" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <img style="width:150px;height:50px;" src="/images/trans.png" class="img-rounded"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <ul class="nav pull-right">
                    <li sec:authorize="${!isAuthenticated()}">
                        <div>
                            <span> Welcome Guest!</span>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li sec:authorize="${isAuthenticated()}">
                        <h4 th:inline="text">Hello [[${#httpServletRequest.remoteUser}]] !</h4>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar-main" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a class="fa fa-home" id="showHome1" href="/"> Home</a></li>

                    <li class="dropdown" sec:authorize="${isAuthenticated()}">
                        <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Searches <b
                                class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                            <li sec:authorize="${isAuthenticated()}">
                                <a class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-up" id="upload" href="/upload"> Upload Data</a>
                            </li>
                            <li sec:authorize="${isAuthenticated()}">
                                <a class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-up" id="ach" href="/ach"> A Search</a>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li sec:authorize="${isAuthenticated()}">
                        <a class="fa fa-search" id="searchT" href="/search"> Search </a>
                    </li>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div
```

After I login, my dropdown menu appears.  I click either sub item and that page is rendered and the url is changed to the appropriate url.  But then when I click the dropdown nothing happens unless I click home or change the url back to "/".

Why would the dropdown menu not work unless the url is "/" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't analyzed your code but I suggest you use the same bootstrap versions (JS+CSS).

Comment: I switched to using Bootstrap v3.3.5 for everything and the issue is still happening.

Comment: I have test with your code in Bootstrap v3.3.5. So, dropdown is working fine. You need to css & js both use in same Bootstrap version. & then remove your browser cache & then check it.

Comment: I am using bootstrap.css v3.3.5 and bootstrap.js v3.3.5 and not only does the menu not work correctly (still requires the "/" mentioned above) but the styling seems to come & go.

Comment: OK, turns out that a few of my pages had bad imports which was causing the styling to go on& off.   Thank you for the help!